# Getting started with image processing using opencv in windows and using in raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, windows

I am learning image processing using opencv in windows. In another project that I am working on, requires the image processing to be done in raspberry pi for object recognition.

Since I do not own a raspberry pi now, I plan to continue working on the image processing on windows (the machine I have access to) using opencv and Visual C++ 2012.

Later ultimately, I need to do it from raspberry pi as the project requires it to be so using the pi camera.

So, to get the image processing running on raspberry pi do i need to rewrite the whole thing being specific to pi in python or can I just somehow make my existing codes working on the windows to work on the pi?

Comment: Hello and welcome. It is noteworthy that stackoverflow also has a [windows-10-iot-core] and a [raspberry-pi2] tag. So in case that you're not satisfied with the answers here, you might want to check over there too. (Note that crossposting of verbatim copies is not encouraged however).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will depend a lot based on what you want to do with the RPi.

If you want to run Windows 10 IOT... I'm admittedly unfamiliar with Windows 10 IOT, but I'll try to answer as best I can. You'll need to upgrade to a minimum of Visual Studio 2013, though 2015 is the official recommendation. For some reason, there doesn't seem to be an official listing of what languages are supported, but I believe I've heard in the past that it only supports .NET languages. This would be problematic for something written in C++.

If you want to run Raspbian, you should drop Visual C++ entirely. It's designed for a Windows environment, and you'd be better off using one designed for Linux. It may be possible, but it will induce headaches. GCC C/C++, or Python would be much less aggravating.

If you need an IDE for the later option, checkout [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/). It's free, and will have a standard toolchain that will run on Linux, even when you're developing on Windows.

Comment: So, I should learn opencv in python or gcc c/c++? I was familiar with programming in C++. (I am not considering Windows 10 on the Pi, I ll be using raspbian. But I would like to learn in widows though the raspbian is linux). Does it mean that it is relatively easy to port my opencv programs developed in windows in gcc c/c++ or python to raspberry pi?

Comment: @BishalHeuju: Provided you're not using platform specific code (things like Windows APIs), things written with gcc c/c++ *should* port pretty painlessly.